# Is there a way to record elapsed time using Prometheus

Tags: java, monitoring, grafana, prometheus

I have a spring-boot application that I have instrumented using `Prometheus` to collect metric data.  Prometheus has metrics such as `Counter` that is good for counting the number of times something has happened, `Gauge` which also keeps count, but can decrease, etc. Is there a metric that would allow me to track the request duration of something? For example, say I want to record the amount of time it takes between when an api call is made, and when the api returns with a response. How would I keep track of the time between when the call is made, and when the api response is received? Then, would it be possible to create a graph where on the `Y` coordinates, I can list the length of time (in seconds or milliseconds) that the response took; then on the `X` axis, have the time-stamp (the time when the metric was collected) be shown?

Answer (score 9):

For timing event size, such as api latency, you probably want a [`Summary`](https://github.com/prometheus/client_java#summary).

You can then calculate an [aggregate average latency](https://www.robustperception.io/common-query-patterns-in-promql/) with:

```
  sum without (instance)(rate(my_summary_latency_seconds_sum[5m]))
/
  sum without (instance)(rate(my_summary_latency_seconds_count[5m])
```

Comment: ... and use Summary#startTimer() to get a timer, and Summary.Timer#observeDuration() to get elapsed time

Answer (score 4):

As you mention [spring-boot](/questions/tagged/spring-boot), you should really look at the [Micrometer](https://micrometer.io/) project. It provides a vendor neutral metric API with support for Prometheus. Micrometer has a specific meter primitive for timers:

```
Timer
   .builder("my.timer")
   .tags("uri", "/api/endpoint")
   .register(registry)
   .record(() -> {
     /* do something */
   });

// or
registry.timer("my.timer", "uri", "api/endpoint").record(() -> {
  /* do something */
});
```

For a Spring-Boot 1.5 project you'd use the `micrometer-spring-legacy` dependency. For Spring-Boot 2 (2.0.0.M7 as of this writing), Micrometer support is included OOTB with `spring-boot-starter-actuator`.

As you mention timing API requests, I assume you are using Spring MVC. There is automatic support for timing these. (You get a `count` for each URI, a `sum` of request duration and as an extra, a `max` for tracking the rolling max during a time window.)

In case you additionally wan't to calculate server-side request latency percentiles, you can enable the generation of histogram buckets, too.

Have a look at the [documentation](https://micrometer.io/docs/ref/spring/1.5#_web_monitoring).